# In tortoisesvn, how to obtain read-only copy of tagged snapshot

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise-svn as my source control. I am new to SVN and tortoise-svn, and I have been trying to figure out how to obtain a read-only copy of a tagged snapshot.

My directory structure looks like:

```
SVN
  MyProject
    branches
    tags
    trunk
      module1
      module2
```

(Currently the 'branches' and 'tags' folders are empty.)

I created a tagged snapshot of module2 by right-clicking on module2, selecting `tortoisesvn >> branch/tag`, as described here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html

I named this tagged snapshot 'module2--alpha1'

I would now like to download the files in this tagged snapshot, to a local folder.  I will not be modifying the files in this local folder.  I will simply be using this downloaded snapshot to build an alpha1 version of my website.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think your question is a little unclear. Do you mean a read-only working copy, or just a copy that is unversioned? Or do you mean "How do I make the tagged snapshot read-only in source control"?

Comment: I added some more details about what I am trying to accomplish.  Is the question now clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- check out a new working copy of that tag. You then get a fully functional working copy from where you could commit changes
- export that tag to a new folder. By exporting, you don't get a working copy but only unversioned files and folders. You can not commit changes you make from there.

I guess in your case, exporting is the way to go since that's more "read only" than checking out.